# facebook login status from outside the application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to know the facebook login status from a chrome extension in the background process. If I try to do the FB.init() i have an error because the init has to be executed from the domain of the app passes in the appid parameter.

How can I call the init outside the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: My problem is _somewhat_ related to yours. Using the Desktop Auth flow from within a chrome extension, I can no longer use the internal Javascript API from facebook (FB.init, FB.login , ... ) because it requires a valid domain in its settings - which is obviously unavailable from within the extension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378733/chrome-extension-facebook-oauth-with-manually-retrieved-access-token

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem (and nobody answered you :( ). I did the login and I have the json data like you, but I don't know how to detect if the user is still loged in the app.