# How do I get Facebook's new OAuth 2.0 access_token with JavaScript in Google Chrome Extention?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, access-token

I want to create simple Google Chrome extention which would display News from Facebook.

News feed can be retrieved by calling this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?**access_token**=...

But I need **access_token**.

Could someone give a hint how to define a JavaScript function which would return **access_token** when given YOUR_APP_ID. This function also should work inside Chrome Extention.

Other examples on the internet did not work, because:

- I don't have a server.
- FB.getLoginStatus does not seem to work.

**EDIT1**:

I've tried this:

```
    function getAccessToken2(YOUR_APP_ID) {
        alert("before FB.init");
        FB.init({
            appId  : YOUR_APP_ID ,
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
        });
        alert("before FB.login");
        FB.login( function (response) {
        alert("response");
            if ( response.authResponse ) {
                alert("response.authResponse");
                var access_token = response.authResponse.access_token;
                alert(access_token);
            }
        } );
    }
```

And I've got:

- alert("before FB.init");
- alert("before FB.login");
- Popup opened. It's URL is [this](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=280834438632804&app_id=280834438632804&client_id=280834438632804&display=popup&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f26be1326c&origin=chrome-extension%253A%252F%252Fedolefjdphajfbpepcfnmldchhbbcjom%252Ff56dba178&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f5df5f2f&response_type=token,signed_request&sdk=joey). The content is:

  ```
  API Error Code: 191
  API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
  Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
  ```

But I've did *NOT* got:

- alert("response");
- alert(access_token);
- no other JavaScript errors seen in debug mode.

**Edit2**
The issue here is that I need to authenticate at Facebook like a desktop application. IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook does allow desktop flow authentication, see [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

You need to specify a special return_uri if using a chrome extension. `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`)

You also need to add `tabs`and the URL to your manifest permissions - i.e.:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://facebook.com/connect/*"
]
```

When a user clicks the login/auth button, you need to perform two steps:

#### Step 1

Redirect the user to the OAUTH page:

```
chrome.tabs.create(
    {
    'url': "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
    }, null);
```

#### Step 2

Add a listener to Tab updates that searches all tabs for the success URL:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
    var lis = this; 
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html") == 0) {
                                var token = tabs[i].url.match(/[\\?&#]auth_token=([^&#])*/i)
                                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(lis);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    });
});
```

Note that I've got a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378733/chrome-extension-facebook-oauth-with-manually-retrieved-access-token) on using the *provided* javascript api for desktop flow, as I've always received the same API error (191)

Comment: auth_token or access_token? For me work with access_token. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
FB.login( function (response) {
    if ( response.authResponse ) {
        var access_token = response.authResponse.access_token;
        alert(access_token);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Edited question. Added response for this comment. This did not worked for me yet.

Comment: This will result in the same error message as the poster described (Api Error 191)