# Chrome packaged application and Facebook redirect url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged Application that I am currently integrating with the Facebook API. The Facebook Javascript SDK requires that I provide the URL of where my application is hosted and for security reasons they only redirect to this url.

The problem is that a Chrome Packaged Application doesn't have a url. I am aware of the [chrome.extension.getURL](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) but this url is not static, it changes per installation. Is there any way to set a URL for a Chrome Application that works for all installations?

Comment: I've tried integrating the Facebook API using the SDK and Client Side Flow, but was unsuccessful. I ended up implementing the Desktop Flow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8698727/420614 - Did you succeed in using the SDK? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you publish your app the id from `chrome.extension.getURL` will not change. The id matches the key used to sign the extension and once you publish an extension to the Web Store that key doesn't change. Developing locally will be more annoying since each time you "load an unpacked extension" it will get a new id.

Comment: I'm learning some new stuff.  Never done a chrome extension before.

Comment: As a workaround during development time, you can add a "key" property to your manifest.json. Using that, the getURL doesn't change. This works for unpublished apps added through the chrome://extensions page. See an example here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/hello-world-sync